# play videos across all browsers and devices

Tags: php, android, html, macos, video

I have been searching on video formats and their compatibility war across browsers. I am working on social networking website where user can upload videos . I can't restrict users to upload video of any specific format as its a social networking site. I converted video of any format to .flv and used video.js plugin to play across all browsers but i found that apple doesn't support flash and and android devices are also not playing .flv video. I searched again i found a solution to play webm file it can run on android devices but unfortunately apple osx doesn't support webm also.

I am stuck what to do now. Should i have to go with converting one video in different formats and play according to browsers but it will take lots of space on my server keeping multiple copy of only video.
If this is the only option left then please tell me minimum number of codecs in which i can convert to run in all browsers and devices

Thanks

Comment: There is no video format that works in all browsers, to make your video work everywhere, you have to encode your video in more than one format

Comment: Dont u think it will take lots of space on server means one video is converted to 3 other codes so if one user has uploaded 30 videos there will be 90 video files. I  am working on SNS.

Comment: Does it make the video uploading process slow? While video is uploaded it is converting to 3 other codecs.

Comment: @Aisha - its actually even worse, unfortunately. if you look at typical YouTube videos for example you will see they often are available at different bit rates in the setting tab. This allows the video player change to the best bit rate as network conditions change, but it also means even more videos for you to store... It will depend on your use case and your users whether this level of quality is required or not.

Comment: @Aisha - btw, if you want to support the most number of browsers/devices with a single format then mp4, using h.264 and AAC with base profile, is probably best at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into [Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/)'s HTML5 video player for the web that tries to use HTML5 video but can do Flash fallback. Or some other similar web video players. You can get pretty decent browser support just by using MP4 in a proper encoding but if you need to support also older browsers and special edge cases you need to have the video in few different formats.

Flowplayer seems to offer some paid services also but I think the basic video player software is still free. The site doesn't seem as easy to navigate as before but they do have pretty good documentation about the supported video formats and browser support and usage instructions for the player.

Check out:

- https://flowplayer.org/docs/setup.html#video-formats
  "MP4 is enough for complete browser support, but providing WebM video as well gives you broader support for HTML5 video which is the preferred technology."
- https://flowplayer.org/docs/encoding.html

**Edit:** Added some more info below.

Flowplayer has good support also for smartphone web browsers, but you might want to be aware of a few [known issues](https://flowplayer.org/docs/known-issues.html).

See licence information about the free version here:

- https://flowplayer.org/license/free-license-faq.html
- https://flowplayer.org/license/

If you need it for commercial projects you might want to checkout their commercial licensing options, see [Flowplayer pricing](https://flowplayer.org/pricing/). At least some of the paid options also give you the ability to rebrand the player interface and you probably get some more features also but I'm not very well informed about all the options available. You should probably read more on their website.

Personally I have used only the free version of Flowplayer on a few websites and it has worked very well.

Comment: Does it support every video format ? i mean if user uploads for e.g .avi .mkv format will it play in all browsers? I have used video js but its not playing in all browsers or devices like android phone, osx, ipad, iphone, safari

Comment: Video format support still depends on browser so to have good browser support you would at least need to convert all uploaded videos to MP4 and then serve that MP4 using Flowplayer. But you would only need to keep the video in MP4 format so single video file per video should be ok. Though additional webm video file would give better native HTML5 video experience for a wider range of browsers.

Comment: Great... will it work in android phones and ipad iphones, osx, safari? And can i use flowplayer for commercial use?

Comment: I updated my post with some more info. If you need more info please read their website or contact Flowplayer support. I can't tell you much more.

Comment: You could also google for "flowplayer alternative" to find more similar software that might better suit your needs.

Comment: You mean I have to convert everything existing on server into MP4? If I do it once, what about the new ones? Doesn't it seem exhausting?

Comment: XlbrlX: Yes, if you want the videos to be viewable by most visitors. If you have a website that gets new videos uploaded often you should have some easy or automated workflow for converting videos from all the source formats you want to support. If the site users can upload videos the conversion should be automated on the server side, or you can make sure users are only allowed to upload MP4. There are many tools for conversion that are quite easy to integrate to server side or client side workflow once you know how to use them. Take a look at ffmpeg for example.